# Best render settings for youtube

Tags: codec, youtube, vegas-pro, render

I am using Vegas Pro as an editing tool for my videos. What codec (currently using x264vfw) and settings are best to render 1080p 60fps video for YouTube if I **don't** care about either rendering time or file size/upload time?

Answer (score 1):

I think this article should help you:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en